# How to turn off "you have to login to comment" on blogs

Tags: blog

When someone wants to comment on my blog they have to login first. How do I change that? I want everyone to be able to comment no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

*Settings > Discussion*, uncheck *Users must be registered and logged in to comment*